# $\varphi^4$ propagator of the complete theory with cut-off in position: can I define things like that?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator, discrete

I am interested in a theory that reduces to a Euclidean $\varphi^4$ one in a specific limit. I want to calculate the full propagator of the theory, which means not using the perturbative expansion. I know it has never been done, and I would like to understand why the simple (and maybe naive?) construction I provide here fails.

In order to introduce a cut-off, I discretize space-time into a lattice of spacing $a$. The kinetic term is then $-\varphi^T A \varphi$, and the potential one $\text{Tr}\left( M(\varphi^T\varphi)^2 \right)$, with $M(\varphi^T\varphi)=\text{diag}\left( \varphi_x^2,\,x\in a^4 \mathbb{Z}^4 \right)$. Then we diagonalize $A$ with orthogonal matrices $O^T$ and $O$: $D_A = O^T A O$. Upon a unitary change of variable $O^T \varphi = \psi$, the kinetic term is $\psi^T D_A \psi$, with $D_A = \text{diag}(\lambda_x, x\in a^4 \mathbb{Z}^4)$. On its side, and with the same change of variable, the potential term is $\text{Tr}\left( M(\psi^T\psi)^2 \right)$. Then I go the standard way of calculating the propagator:
\begin{equation}
    \langle \varphi_x \varphi_y \rangle_{a} = \langle O_{xw}\psi_w \psi_z O_{zy}\rangle_{a} = O_{xw}\langle \psi_w \psi_z \rangle_{a}O_{zy}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
And,
\begin{align}
    \langle \psi_w \psi_z \rangle_{a} =& \langle \psi \otimes \psi \rangle_{a}|_{wz}
\nonumber \\
    =& \iint \cdots \int \psi\otimes \psi \prod_{x\in a^4\mathbb{Z}^4} d\mu_x\left. \vphantom{\int}\right|_{wz};\,\,\, \forall x\in a^4\mathbb{Z}^4,\int d\mu_x = 1
\nonumber \\
    \stackrel{(\ast)}{=}& \iint \cdots \int M(\psi^T \psi) \prod_{x\in a^4\mathbb{Z}^4} d\mu_x\left. \vphantom{\int}\right|_{wz}
\nonumber \\
    =& \left.\text{diag}\left(\int \psi_z^2\, d\mu_z,\,z\in a^4\mathbb{Z}^4\right)\right|_{wz}
\nonumber \\
    =:\,& \left.\text{diag}\left(G(\lambda_z),\,z\in a^4\mathbb{Z}^4\right)\right|_{wz}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
The $(\ast)$ equality comes from the fact that the measures $d\mu_x$ are all even in $\psi$. Direct evaluation of $G(\lambda_z)$ shows it can be expanded in a Laurent series in $\lambda_z$. Since $(2)$ is diagonal, we can deduce:
\begin{equation}
    \langle \phi_x \phi_y \rangle_{a}=O_{xw}\langle \psi_w \psi_z \rangle_{a}O_{zy}=G(A)|_{xy} \stackrel{!}{=} \langle x | G(A) | y \rangle. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Now, what prevents me from doing so? Is it an error to write the potential term like this, and why?

Comment: I suppose that by $\mathrm{d}\mu_x$ you mean $\mathrm{d}\varphi_x \exp(-[\varphi^\top A \varphi]_x + \varphi_x^4)$. It is not at all clear why $\int\mathrm{d}\mu_x=1$ in this case.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I mean almost this, but with $Z_x=\int d\varphi_x \text{exp}([\varphi^T A \varphi]_x-\varphi_x^4)$ as denominator, so that the measure is $d\mu_x =d\varphi_x \text{exp}([\varphi^T A \varphi]_x-\varphi_x^4)/Z_x $. Hence the integral is 1.